# Django + Heroku Database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

When editing the settings.py file in my Django app, I have the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb', 
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Can someone explain what exactly is the result?

On the one hand, I have set up a postgresql database - which until now has been sqlite and used just locally for development.

Now I am deploying to Heroku, I have imported dj_database_url which I think sets up the link between my database and Heroku's own postgresql setup.

So does it matter what I set as the database, if Heroku is going to convert it to postgresql regardless?

Comment: your code will work on heroku but heroku create new database on the heroku environ .. You have to dump and import to heroku postgres ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point having both of these. The last line of that snippet overwrites the default database config you defined previously.

**Edit**

This isn't anything to do with whether or not you use manage.py runserver. The only point is that Heroku defines an environment variable, DATABASE_URL, which contains the database location and credentials, which is then parsed by dj_database_url. What you should be doing is defining the same thing locally: the [dj_database_url docs](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url#url-schema) have some examples of the format to use for different db backends.

The best way to set up the env variable is to put it in a file called .env in your development directory, and then always start your app via `foreman start` (Foreman should have been installed by the Heroku toolbelt). See the Heroku [getting started docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally) for more.

But if this doesn't work for you you can always just do `export DATABASE_URL=whatever` in your shell before you run manage.py for the first time.

Comment: What if I just manage.py runserver? What database setup is applied when run locally like this instead of through heroku?

Comment: @Jack you will get error when runserver locally because that configure incorrectly. It's should be `DATABASES['mydb']`

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is: what should I use for when developing locally? And then, when it's time to deploy, can I just import dj_database_url and use that?

Comment: Foreman no longer ships with Heroku tool belt. The command is `heroku local` now.